# How to get nth-child to skip items based on class

Tags: html, css

I have a system that dynamically add classes to items, and I am hoping to be able to use `:nth-child(3n)` on the items that don't have that class, i.e. it "skips" the items with the dynamic class.

I created a CodePen demonstrating what I want and showing that I *hoped* using `:not()` would work, but it doesn't. I would hope it removes it from the items selected, but it doesn't appear to do that. :-/

I also tried replacing `:nth-child` with `:nth-of-type` in the example (which makes even *more* sense) to me, but it didn't change anything.

http://codepen.io/CWSpear/pen/qoaJC/

It would be awesome to be able to do this *without* JavaScript.

Comment: You can create a class that overrides overlapping CSS. Or do you want a default? How to `:nth-of-type(3n +1)`.

Comment: @ArrayKnight, I *really* thought `:nth-of-type` would work, but I guess it only works with elements (or at least *doesn't* work with the `:not` pseudo-selector). :-( **(edit)** looks like ArrayKnight deleted his comment?

Comment: @brcrash, that `.peel` class could be added to other and multiple items, and I don't know ahead of time which, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: What will happen with true class `.peel`? I think I could not explain it. :)

Comment: @CWSpear I'm afraid that this is not possible with pure CSS. `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` looks through the children tree of parent element, not through a list of `element.class` or `element:not(.class)`.